# Chartboost shows ad successfully but still "Failed to load Interstitial, no ad found !"

Tags: admob, chartboost

In `applicationDidBecomeActive`, if `didFailToLoadInterstitial` is called, I popup admob interstitial. But `chartboost` shows ad successfully and still calls `didFailToLoadInterstitial`, so both two interstitial ad popup.

How to solved it?
How can I know chartboost shows ad successfully? Then I don't need to popup admob interstitial.

**Edit:**

```
- (void)didDismissInterstitial:(NSString *)location {

    NSLog(@"dismissed interstitial at location %@", location);

    [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheInterstitial:location];

}
```

I must use autocache in the above code because it can reduce time to load ads immediately.

I need to show chartboost ad, if it can't show, then the app should show admob Interstitial ad instead.

The   `[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheInterstitial:location];` and  `[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];` functions both will call `didFailToLoadInterstitial` if they load error.

Can they call different `didFailToLoadInterstitial` functions? So I can just call admob Interstitial when chartboost showInterstitial loads error.

Is there a way to know how many chartboost ads available to show now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL donotShowAdmob;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *myTimer;

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Begin a user session. Must not be dependent on user actions or any prior network requests.
    // Must be called every time your app becomes active.
    [Chartboost startWithAppId:@"537a2fe489b0bb64ac855ce2" appSignature:@"38cc6952604d5ab537deb627f2d91087f430df2b" delegate:self];

    if(![[AdManager inst] isRemoveAd])
    {
        [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
        [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationQuit];
    }
}

-(void) errorLoadAd
{
    if(!_donotShowAdmob)
    {
        MainViewController* cont=self.viewController;
        [cont showInterstitial ];
    }
}
- (BOOL)shouldDisplayInterstitial:(NSString *)location {
    _donotShowAdmob=TRUE;
    if (_myTimer!=nil) {
        [_myTimer invalidate];
        _myTimer = nil;
    }

    _myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.0
      target: self
      selector:@selector(onTick:)
      userInfo: nil repeats:NO];

// Otherwise return YES to display the interstitial
    return YES;

}

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    _donotShowAdmob=FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Tick...");
}
- (void)didFailToLoadInterstitial:(NSString *)location withError:(CBLoadError)error {
    [self errorLoadAd];

    switch(error){
        case CBLoadErrorInternetUnavailable: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, no Internet connection !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorInternal: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, internal error !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorNetworkFailure: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, network error !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorWrongOrientation: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, wrong orientation !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorTooManyConnections: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, too many connections !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorFirstSessionInterstitialsDisabled: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, first session !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorNoAdFound : {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, no ad found !");
        } break;
        case CBLoadErrorSessionNotStarted : {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, session not started !");
        } break;
        default: {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Interstitial, unknown error !");
        }
    }
}
```

I use a NSTimer to solve it, in 3 seconds after chartboost shows ok, don't show admob Interstitial. But still sometimes, two ads shows...

**Edit:**
Solved by `hasCachedInterstitial`